# Add custom page link with anchor

Tags: menus, add-menu-page

In my admin section I would like to add in Appearance > Menus > some custom pages to add to my menu. I have two different menu one for the home page and one for the others pages. In my home page menu I add the menu elements as link because I need to give to the href the id of html element so i can 'redirect' in a specific point in my page, so my link is '#gallery'. In the menù for all the other page I the link should be 'http://my_domain/home/#gallery. Is there a  way to add dinamically this link to the page list? I hope I was clear.
Thanks

Comment: I have just added a Custom Link menu item, href is http://example.com/contact/#content and when I am in the contact page, the menu item works fine, in terms of jumping to content using the ID of the division without reloading the page..

Comment: I'm developing in local so my custom link will be localhost/folder_name/home/#content. If I just add the link when I'll deploy my blog I will need to change all this link. I'm looking for a dynamic method to do that.

Comment: Then add only `/home/#content` as a link..

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for an answer for this but suddenly I got the idea and it works!

In the menu settings just add the anchor link just like an html link code `<a href="#anchor" >titulo </a>`

So with WP is the same but only adding the anchor in the field link

[image]

This will create the same anchor on every page to link a section which is active also en every single page, this could be a contact form, sign up, suscribe form, etc.

[image]

So this will be addressed like `http://domain.com/postID/#sugerir`

[image]

**What happen on pages where this anchor won't work or is not needed?**

You can hide the navigation-item with css depending on each case
For me is important on every single post to link a form to suggest ideas (Sugiere un tema).

Answer (score -1):

Go to the custom link tab, and in the url box just add:
?page_id=[id_number]#[anchor]

That's what worked for me after a little playing around. Make sure WordPress doesn't add http:// before it.

Other thoughts: Would be nice if WordPress just had an extra box to go with the pages where you could just paste in the anchor.

Comment: Though I must add on, I was doing this for pages. I imagine you would write ?p=[id_number]#[anchor]